# Error in generating list of dates

Tags: python

I have a python script

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta


def generateDateList(date,month,year):
   today = date(year, month, date)
   arrDates = []
   for i in range(0,5):
      arrDates.append(datetime.strftime(today + timedelta(days=i),"%d-%m-%y"))
   return arrDates

print generateDateList(4,12,2017)
```

But i get this error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print generateDateList(4,12,2017)
  File "test.py", line 11, in generateDateList
    today = date(year, month, date)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Why is it failing? I substituted the function with values and it worked. Should i convert the function inputs to integer again?

Comment: You've overriden the global `date` with your local `date` variable. Do not do that. To be extra-sure, just `import datetime` and then use `datetime.date`, `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.timedelta` where needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line - `def generateDateList(date,month,year):`

The name of the first argument `date` shadows the name `date` imported at the top. You need to rename the argument to something like `day` inside your function.

As written, `date` is actually an integer you pass to the function, and calling it results in an error you are seeing.

Comment: It happens from time to time, no worries. :)

Answer (score 1):

Two options.

Option No.1 (import datetime):

```
import datetime

def generateDateList(date, month, year):
   today = datetime.date(year, month, date)
   arrDates = []
   for i in range(0,5):
      arrDates.append(datetime.datetime.strftime(today + datetime.timedelta(days=i),"%d-%m-%y"))
   return arrDates

print generateDateList(4, 12, 2017)
```

Option No.2 (rename date parameter to day):

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

def generateDateList(day,month,year):
   today = date(year, month, day)
   arrDates = []
   for i in range(0,5):
      arrDates.append(datetime.strftime(today + timedelta(days=i),"%d-%m-%y"))
   return arrDates

print generateDateList(4,12,2017)
```

The problem is the fact you have a parameter with the same name of the date() function.